# is there any Google API to get list of regions with out project in the url path?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to retrieve all regions without needing the project name in the URL? I could not find the API.The equivalent CLI is "gcloud compute regions list".
do you know equivalent API URL?

Thanks
Kovi

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to retrieve all regions without needing the project name
>   in the URL?

You will need your Project ID and sometimes the Project Number for most API operations. The Project Name is not used.

The Project ID is required as not all zones are available to all projects. This API returns the zones that your Project ID can access.

This API does not return all Google Cloud zones. Some zones are not available to you.

> The equivalent CLI is "gcloud compute regions list". do you know
>   equivalent API URL?

The URL is:

```
https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones
```

The API documentation for this command is:

[Compute Engine - Method: zones.list](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/zones/list)

The API documentation includes examples in a number of languages such as Python, Go, Java, etc.